# CSS styling not manipulating JS rendered images

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have attached below the .js and .css files. The css styling seems to have no effect on the rendered images. I dont know why that is the case. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Row.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
import './Row.css';

const baseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({title, fetchUrl}) {

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            setMovies(request.data.results);
            return request;
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchUrl]);

    console.table(movies);

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            <div className="row__posters">
                {movies.map(movie => (
                    <img
                        className="row__poster" 
                        src={`${baseUrl}${movie.poster_path}`} 
                        alt={movie.name}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>        
    );
}

export default Row;
```

Row.css

```
.row__posters {
  width: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.row__posters img`?

Comment: you missed s' in `row__poster` in the React part

Comment: As they already told you, there is an 's' at the css part that you don't need, because there you are targeting the container, not the image.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an 's' missing off the end of the class name tied to the image.

```
row__poster
```

Not

```
row__posters
```